# Do ionizing hair-dryers reduce frizz and drying time?

Tags: electromagnetism, consumer-products, hair

The new wave in Hair Dryer technology involves marketing benefits based on Ionization. Is there any evidence for any of this though?

[Conair® Turbo 1875](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00132ZG3U):

> "Ionic technology helps enhance your hair's natural shine and eliminates frizz for healthy-looking, smooth results. The high-torque motor speeds air through your hair for faster drying and styling while ionic technology reduces frizz and flyaways with ease."

[BaByliss Pro BABP2800](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UHN0I6)

> "ionic technology emits negative ions eliminate static, reduces drying time."

Comment: I'd be curious what do they have to say about oxygen ions touching your hair.